# How to replace epoch timestamps in a file with other formats?

Tags: text-processing, sed, date

I have a file that contains epoch dates which I need converting to human-readable. I already know how to do the date conversion, eg:

```
[server01 ~]$ date -d@1472200700
Fri 26 Aug 09:38:20 BST 2016
```

..but I'm struggling to figure out how to get `sed` to walk through the file and convert all the entries.
The file format looks like this:

```
#1472047795
ll /data/holding/email
#1472047906
cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
#1472048038
ll /data/holding/web
```

Comment: For future reference (assuming this is a Bash history file; it looks like one), look to the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` shell variable to control the format at time of writing.

Comment: @Toby the value of HISTTIMEFORMAT is used when displaying (to stdout), but only its status (set to anything even null vs unset) matters when writing HISTFILE.

Comment: Thanks @dave, I didn't know that (not being a user of history times myself).

Comment: `date -d` is not portable to say Solaris... I'm assuming this is on a system with mostly GNU tools? (GNU AWK / Perl tend to be the more portable methods to deal with date conversions). `gawk '{ if ($0 ~ /^#[0-9]*$/) {print strftime("%c",substr($0,2)); } else {print} }' < file` (`strftime` seems non-portable...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming consistent file format, with `bash` you can read the file line by line, test if it's in given format and then do the conversion:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do [[ $i =~ ^#([0-9]{10})$ ]] && \
      date -d@"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done <file.txt
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is an array whose first element is the first captured group in Regex matching, `=~`, in this case the epoch.

---

If you want to keep the file structure:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do if [[ $i =~ ^#([0-9]{10})$ ]]; then printf '#%s\n' \
   "$(date -d@"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")"; else printf '%s\n' "$i"; fi; done <file.txt
```

this will output the modified contents to STDOUT, to save it in a file e.g. `out.txt`:

```
while ...; do ...; done >out.txt
```

Now if you wish, you can replace the original file:

```
mv out.txt file.txt
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
#1472047795
ll /data/holding/email
#1472047906
cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
#1472048038
ll /data/holding/web

$ while IFS= read -r i; do [[ $i =~ ^#([0-9]{10})$ ]] && date -d@"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done <file.txt
Wed Aug 24 20:09:55 BDT 2016
Wed Aug 24 20:11:46 BDT 2016
Wed Aug 24 20:13:58 BDT 2016

$ while IFS= read -r i; do if [[ $i =~ ^#([0-9]{10})$ ]]; then printf '#%s\n' "$(date -d@"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")"; else printf '%s\n' "$i"; fi; done <file.txt
#Wed Aug 24 20:09:55 BDT 2016
ll /data/holding/email
#Wed Aug 24 20:11:46 BDT 2016
cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
#Wed Aug 24 20:13:58 BDT 2016
ll /data/holding/web
```

Comment: Nice....that prints the converted date to screen, now how do I get that command to replace the entries in the file?

Comment: @machinist Check my edits..

Comment: If you are using a recent version of `bash`, `printf` can do the conversion itself: `printf '#%(%F %H)T\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`.

Answer (score 15):

While it's possible with GNU `sed` with things like:

```
sed -E 's/^#([0-9]+).*$/date -d @\1/e'
```

That would be terribly inefficient (and is easy to introduce arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities<sup>1</sup>) as that would mean running one shell and one `date` command for each `#xxxx` line, virtually as [bad as a shell `while read` loop](/q/169716). Here, it would be better to use things like `perl` or `gawk`, that is text processing utilities that have date conversion capabilities built-in:

```
perl  -MPOSIX -pe 's/^#(\d+).*/ctime $1/se'
```

Or:

```
gawk '/^#/{$0 = strftime("%c", substr($0, 2))};1'
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> If we had written `^#([0-9]).*` instead of `^#([0-9]).*$` (as I did in an earlier version of this answer), then in multi-byte locales like UTF-8 ones (the norm nowadays), with an input like `#1472047795<0x80>;reboot`, where that `<0x80>` is the byte value 0x80 which does not form a valid character, that `s` command would have ended up running `date -d@1472047795<0x80>; reboot` for instance. While with the extra `$`, those lines would not be substituted. An alternative approach would be: `s/^#([0-9])/date -d @\1 #/e`, that is leave the part after the `#xxx` date as a shell comment</sub>

Comment: What about using just a [single instance of `date -f`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306781/34061) to do all the conversions in a stream-wise manner?

Comment: The perl command seems to add a new line after ctime $1 and I can't find any way to remove it.

Comment: @Alex. Right. See edit. Adding the `s` flag makes so that `.*` also includes the newline on input. You can also use `strftime "%c", localtime $1`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks so much. It's a great answer.

Comment: Where does the perl command reference the file it is using as input and output?

Comment: @zylstra, `-p` with `perl` enables a `sed`-like mode, so input comes from files given as arguments (though see also [Security implications of running perl -ne '...' \*](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013)) or stdin if no argument and output goes to stdout like in `sed`. See `perldoc perlrun` for details.

Answer (score 4):

All the other answers spawn a new `date` process for every epoch date that needs to be converted.  This could potentially add performance overhead if your input is large.

However GNU date has a handy `-f` option that allows a single process instance of `date` to continuously read input dates without the need for a new fork.  So we can use `sed`, `paste` and `date` in this manner such that each one only gets spawned once (2x for `sed`) regardless of how large the input is:

```
$ paste -d '\n' <( sed '2~2d;y/#/@/' epoch.txt | date -f - ) <( sed '1~2d' epoch.txt )
Wed Aug 24 07:09:55 PDT 2016
ll /data/holding/email
Wed Aug 24 07:11:46 PDT 2016
cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
Wed Aug 24 07:13:58 PDT 2016
ll /data/holding/web
$
```

- The two `sed` commands respectively basically delete even and odd lines of the input; the first one also replaces `#` with `@` to give the correct epoch timestamp format.
- The first `sed` output is then piped to `date -f` which does the required date conversion, for every line of input that it receives.
- These two streams are then interlaced into the single required output using `paste`.  The `<( )` constructs are [bash process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) that effectively trick paste into thinking it is reading from given filenames when it is in fact reading the output piped from the command inside.  `-d '\n'` tells `paste` to separate odd and even output lines with a newline.  You could change (or remove) this if for example you want the timestamp on the same line as the other text.

Note that there are several GNUisms and Bashisms in this command.  This is not Posix-compliant and should not be expected to be portable outside of the GNU/Linux world.  For example `date -f` does something else on OSXes BSD `date` variant.

Comment: `date -d` (from the question) is also non-portable... (On FreeBSD it will try to mess with DST settings, on Solaris it will give an error...) The question does not specify an OS though...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg yes, this is addressed in the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: I mean that the asker's sample also has portability issues... (They should probably have tagged an OS...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date format you have in your post is what you want, the following regex should fit your needs.

```
sed -E 's/\#(1[0-9]{9})(.*)/echo \1 $(date -d @\1)/e' log.file
```

Be mindful of the fact this will only replace one epoch per line.

Comment: I'm getting the following error with that command:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 48: invalid reference \3 on 's' command's RHS`

Comment: My mistake, edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

using sed :

```
sed -r 's/\#([0-9]*)/echo $(date -d @\1)/eg' test.txt
```

output :

```
ر أغس 24 16:09:55 EET 2016
ll /data/holding/email
ر أغس 24 16:11:46 EET 2016
cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
ر أغس 24 16:13:58 EET 2016
ll /data/holding/web
```

as my locale language is Arabic :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution how to do that in a pipeline

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/^/echo "/; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/`date -d @\1`/; s/$/"/' | bash
```