# Convert epoch date output from command result to human readable

Tags: linux, command-line, date

I've been trying to nut this out, but I'm stumped... I've tried to extrapolate the commands I found at [How to replace epoch timestamps in a file with other formats?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306576/how-to-replace-epoch-timestamps-in-a-file-with-other-formats), but I'm can't get it yet.

My system has a command to read values from a database, one of the values I can read is in epoch time format:

```
[user@Dreadnaught config]# dbviewer -t Isagraf5.Resource._1.CompileDate
1488303650
```

If I manually copy the result to the date command, it works fine:

```
[user@Dreadnaught config]$ date -d@1488303650
Tue Feb 28 17:40:50 UTC 2017
```

I want to get this **as a single command** (so I can just add it to my alias list instead of having to load a sh script). I've tried all sorts of ways to pipe the result from the first command to the second, but I can't figure it out. What am I missing?

From the other referenced question, I've managed to join the result from the dbviwer query onto the date command, but not execute it.

```
[user@Dreadnaught config]$ dbviewer -t Isagraf5.Resource._1.CompileDate | sed 's/^//; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/date -d @\1/;s/$//'
date -d @1488303650
[user@Dreadnaught config]$ . dbviewer -t Isagraf5.Resource._1.CompileDate | sed 's/^//; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/date -d @\1/;s/$//'
-ash: /usr/bin/dbviewer: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2):

```
alias dbdate='date -d@"$( dbviewer -t Isagraf5.Resource._1.CompileDate )"'
```

You should now be able to use `dbdate` as an alias for

```
date -d@"$( dbviewer -t Isagraf5.Resource._1.CompileDate )"
```

This command will run `dbviewer -t Isagraf5.Resource._1.CompileDate` and call `date` with its output inserted after the `@`.

`$(...)` is a command substitution. It will be substituted by the output of the command inside the `$(...)`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! The combination of ' and " and substituting instead of piping is what I was missing.
Works perfectly, thanks.